# Защита каталогов и т.п htaccess

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess

Подскажите, как грамотно составить htaccess, чтобы был тотальный запрет на показ содержимого сайта (каталоги, вложенные каталоги, файлы и т.п.), если человек переходит по директориям..например, убрать возможность смотреть содержимое JS файлов через прямой путь (если это возможно)

Comment: «например, убрать возможность смотреть содержимое JS файлов через прямой путь (если это возможно)» - возможно, но лишено смысла: ведь тогда юзерагент вообще не сможет получить js-файлы с сервера, и скрипты от страниц "отвалятся". Протокол HTTP просто не знает такого типа запроса как "смотреть"... для получения ассетов (независимо от цели), в большинстве случаев используется один и тот же `GET`.

Comment: Но я же могу, например, добавить в список исключения IP адрес своего сервера (сайта), чтобы только он мог обращаться к вложениям..или нет ?

Comment: Да, это возможно. Но тогда просматривать страницы сайта с JS скриптами, можно будет только с сервера. А для посетителей (человеков, которые его посещают через интернет), страницы будут без JS-скриптов... так как доступа к файлам скриптов у них не будет, ведь их (посетителей) IP-адреса не совпадут с IP-адресом сервера. Это вроде очевидно...

Comment: И то верно..не правильно себе представил это просто, Спасибо!